# Multilanguage: Adding custom language to Web content php

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, echo, multilingual

I have a forum website and I want to add various different custom languages in my forum.

By meaning languages I only want to change my system texts NOT WHAT USERS post in there. Now by languages I don't want any Spanish/French implementation.  I want to do custom languages like *Funky/Punk/Ghetto* these.

eg - **English**  -  Hello, what is your question?

**Ghetto** - Aiyo, whatya question man!?

Now I can create a log in `users` mysql table called `lang` and then use `sessions` to detect what language he/she wants.

*But problem is rewriting my whole code of >30k lines and best method to do it*

Now I don't want to make `home_en.php` or `home_ghetto.php` language duplicate files for a single page.

Neither I think doing a `switch-case` before each `echo` which prints my website system text is also a good idea.

I'm left with no possibilities I can see therefore I need visions of yours to enlighten me and get me out of this darkness.

**ps - how does big sites Google, Microsoft etc manage to do that?**

Answer (score 0):

The way this is normally done is to have a "language table" with an id.  All the text on your site is held in that table, each text section with an ID identifying the language, and a TextID identifying which block of text.

When so when your user comes to the site, and their preference is English, the text from the ID matching English is shown.  Same thing for other languages.

```
--------------------------------------
| id | language | text      | textId |
| 1  | English  | Hello     |   1    |
| 2  | Spanish  | Hola      |   1    |
| 3  | German   | Guten Tag |   1    |
--------------------------------------
```

The idea here is that when the user comes to the site, you pull from your database like:

```
SELECT text from languageTable where id=1 and textID=1
```

Which would return "hello"
or

```
SELECT text from languageTable where id=2 and textID=1
```

Which would return "Hola"

The tough part is populating the table with every single bit of text on your site with every single language you'd need.  But once that's done, your pages populate with the desired language.

Comment: Can you gimme an idea what are the columns of table

Comment: So you mean more pressure on server. Won't it be faster if I instead store those texts in a php array than mysql table?

Comment: It depends.  That's a lot of text for PHP to go through, as opposed to just calling the database.  Plus, it's easier to maintain. I actually worked at a place where the site traffic was ridiculous (like 1000s of hits an hour).  And this is how we managed multiple languages.

Comment: So I should do 1) One Query  `SELECT text from languageTable where id=2` and store the texts in php arrays and then display accordingly or 2) Hundreds of query  `SELECT text from languageTable where id=2 and textID=1`  whenever necessary and display them?   `option 2` looks obsolete to me.

Comment: You pull ALL of the id=2 (or whatever) at once, and drop THAT into an array.  Then use PHP/HTML to place the text where they are needed by the TextID.  So it's not hundreds of queries.  That would be ridiculous and a terrible burden on the server.

Comment: Thanks. But out of curiosity I found that xml can also be a possibility.  I want to know whether you prefer xml over this method?

Comment: I do not.  But it's mostly because all you're doing is populating an XML instead of a database.  Once you parse that XML, you're still going to have to use PHP/HTML to place the text.  If you were to do that, you may as well stick with the straight-up PHP method.  Which, again, is more difficult to maintain.